# Is there any way around this conditional hook workaround?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm using NextJS's `useRouter` to access the router like so:

```js
const router = useRouter();
```

but however, when my component renders, I tend to notice that `router` can be `null` until it actually instantiates. My workaround would be doing something like this:

```js
const router = useRouter();

if (!router) return null;

return (
  // ... jsx
);
```

However, I have a custom hook that I'm using and it's dependent on the router's queries:

```js
const router = useRouter();

if (!router) return null;

const {data} = useCustomHook(router.query.id);

return ( //.... )
```

But I get an eslint error like so:

```
React Hook "useCustomHook" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?
```

My workaround is to make two separate components to handle this conditional:

```js
const HookComponent = ({ id }) => {
  const { data } = useCustomHook(id);
  return ( // ....)
}

const HookComponentWrapper = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (!router) return null;

  return <HookComponent id={router.query.id}/>
}
```

My question is: is it possible to avoid having to add that wrapper just for a conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `router` can sometimes be null you can use guard clauses to access up to the id passed to the hook. `useCustomHook` still needs to handle null input gracefully.

```
const {data} = useCustomHook(router && router.query && router.query.id);
```

Or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) if your build allows it

```
const {data} = useCustomHook(router?.query?.id);
```

At this point I'd suggest just passing the `router` object and handle extracting what you need from it in any custom hook.